# Validar tipo de fichero input file

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, angularjs

Tengo un formulario donde se puede cargar ficheros solo excel, word y pdf

```
<input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .doc, .docx, .pdf" name="report" />
```

Cuando busco en el pc solo me aparecen ficheros de este tipo, pero si estoy supongamos en la carpeta Descargar y aqui hay un fichero test.java, si voy a la ruta de esa carpeta y en vez de seleccionar el fichero pongo el nombre del fichero java, lo carga y me lo guarda.

¿Cómo puedo controlar esto en el servidor con java?

Comment: Podrías utilizar un evento onchange="return validarFichero()" en el input, y en caso que no cumpla con la condición de la extensión que devuelva false la funcion validarFichero

Comment: ahi puedo controlar la extension pero y si en la carpeta hay un fichero que se llama test.java y pongo solo test y me lo carga tendria el mismo problema, deberia controlar mas que la extension el tipo de fichero?

Comment: Yo me refiero que la validacion validarFichero, se ejecutaría hasta que el usuario aceptara el archivo, entoces ahi en caso que no sea un archivo validado, regresar false y enviar un mensaje al usuario.

Comment: Creo q deberia controlarlo mas en el lado del servidor, si pongo la funcion que dices, el usuario modifica el script, podra seguir subiendo el fichero

Comment: Pues si es un usuario avanzado si podría modificarlo, en este caso podrías agregar una segunda validación en el servidor al momento de guardar o antes, para validar el tipo de archivo y así asegurarte

Comment: Si creo q sera lo mejor, sabria controlarlo por nombre pero no se si se puede hacer esto mismo por tipo de fichero

Comment: Para validar el tipo fichero, se podría ser por extension y/o por el parametro type que genera el input al enviar el formulario

Answer (score 0):

Podrías obtener la extension del archivo encontrado, 
y filtrar que solo sea admisible si la extension es una de las acordadas. 
En javascript puedes combinar `split()` y `pop()` para ello.

```
return filename.split('.').pop();
```

Al usar `split()` en el fichero, separas el nombre de la extension,
Posteriormente, al usar `pop()` obtienes el ultimo de la cadena, el cual seria la extension.

Comment: ahi puedo controlar la extension pero y si en la carpeta hay un fichero que se llama test.java y pongo solo test y me lo carga tendria el mismo problema, deberia controlar mas que la extension el tipo de fichero?

Comment: Si lo filtras por los mencionados arriba, no veo como java sea igual a ellos... tu si ??

Comment: Creo q deberia controlarlo mas en el lado del servidor, si pongo la funcion que dices, el usuario modifica el script, podra seguir subiendo el fichero

Comment: Si alguien modifica el script claro, puede subir lo que quiera, si quieres controlarlo desde el servidor tampoco es mala idea.

Comment: creo q sera la mejor opcion, Sabria controlarlo por nombre pero no se si se puede hacer esto mismo por tipo de fichero

Comment: si modifican el script el usuario podrá subir lo que quiera, si cambia el html del input file igual subirá lo que quiera... lo que te llegue a tu servidor, tienes que validar que tenga el formato que requieres.

Comment: Si eso ya quedo claro, el busca como hacerlo ahora